# Creating Web View with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

Im new to android and im trying to create a web View in with fragments 
and i am getting an error in the Adapter class at the WebViewFragment getitem(),
Saying" THE RETURN TYPE IS INCOMPATIBLE WITH THE fragmentPagerAdapter" please help because im stuck

```
import homePage.HotDeals;
import homePage.NewArrivals;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.webkit.WebViewFragment;

public class HomePageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

public HomePageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public WebViewFragment getItem(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(index){
    case 0:
        return new NewArrivals();
    case 1:
        return new HotDeals();

    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 static public class MyWebViewFragment extends Fragment {

  WebView myWebView;
  final static String myBlogAddr = "http://android-er.blogspot.com";
  String myUrl;


  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_webfragment, container, false);
   myWebView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.mywebview);

   myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);                
   myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

   if(myUrl == null){
    myUrl = myBlogAddr;
   }
   myWebView.loadUrl(myUrl);

         return view;

  }

  private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
         @Override
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          myUrl = url;
             view.loadUrl(url);
             return true;
         }
     }

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   setRetainInstance(true);
  }

 }

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  MyWebViewFragment fragment = 
    (MyWebViewFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myweb_fragment);
  WebView webView = fragment.myWebView;

  if(webView.canGoBack()){
   webView.goBack();
  }else{
   super.onBackPressed();
  }
 }

}
```

For further reference : 
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/04/embed-webview-in-fragment.html

You can also use WebViewFragment. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewFragment.html